# Div height and width inconsistent to screen dimensions in DevTools in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

The mobile emulator of Chrome dev tools a div is 320 x 362, and so is the window but it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why this would be? Is it a bug?

Comment: Make the window bigger so you can see `DPR` in the device toolbar in the page. I guess it's not `1.0`

Answer (score 2):

It may be some sort of a bug in a recent version of Chrome (I am experiencing this for the first time on 83.0.4103.97). If you make the screen the same size outside of the mobile emulator, this doesn't happen, interestingly. For me it also doesn't kick in until screen width goes below about 360px.

The fix that worked for me was to add this inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"/>
```

Adding this *without* the `minimum-scale` tag seems to be standard practice, but adding the `minimum-scale` made it work for me.