# Edge dev tool width measurement is not the same as the element is

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a non-English speaker, it's Really hard for me to describe the detail, sorry for any confusion.

I'm learning to build a responsive web in React and inspect it in Edge dev tool, then I found that the width shown on top is not the same as my root div shown below when the width is less than about 550px, what should I do?

[image: The problem looks like this]

I tried testing it in Firefox dev tool and it looks fine.
Or maybe I should not testing my responsive layout on borwser dev tool?

Comment: Please include a text-based [mcve] showing the issue in the question itself.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I found the solution to this problem. I want to paste a reproducible example but can't even decide which part of code should I paste because I don't do anything to the #root div, but still thanks to your comment!

Answer (score 0):

[Div height and width inconsistent to screen dimensions in DevTools in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044935/div-height-and-width-inconsistent-to-screen-dimensions-in-devtools-in-chrome)

Suddenly found a same question before, the problem is solved after adding minimum-scale=1 in meta tag like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```